# expressing a feeling

Tags: names

I'm looking for a name for my blog, crisp yet interesting. The idea is, when we tear paper into tiny bits and let it fly from the roof, it looks like a beautiful whirlpool of paper shower, i couldn't express this in words. The closest I could come up with is paper bits, but that sounds least interesting for a blog name.
P.S - I would be posting poetry, paintings and photography in it.

Comment: I think questions seeking "product name" suggestions are Off Topic anyway, but how about [***snowglobe**?*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Snow-Globes/b?ie=UTF8&node=3028641031) Or [***kaleidoscope**?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaleidoscope)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a name to be suggested.

Comment: ......Confetti?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paper bits you describe would be called **[confetti](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confetti)**

> small bits or streamers of brightly colored paper made for throwing

Which might look something like this;

[image]

So confetti would be a good word to use as a base for your blog title.

Answer (score -1):

When I shut my eyes and imagined what you described this is what I saw:

Maze of Whispering Snowflakes

Comment: +1 purely for the inventive imagery.